# Cannot Split Table with EF 5 - Code First - with existing database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to split a legacy user table into two entities using a one to one mapping but keep getting migration errors stating that my database is out of sync, even though everything (i think is mapped) and i am trying to make a one-to-one relationship.

This is an existing database (although i am using code first as migrations will become important down the line) but i have not added any changes to the database (although i am unsure what exactly the one-to-one table split expects), i keep getting this:

```
The model backing the 'Context' context has changed since the database was created.     Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
```

I can update the database (either manually or via Migrations) but have no idea what is actually out of sync as no new fields have been added and the names match up.

**BaseEntity:**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

**Membership Model:**

```
public class Membership : BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool Approved { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

**Profile Model:**

```
public class Profile : BaseEntity<Guid>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public Membership Membership { get; set; }
}
```

**Membership Mapping (this has the 1 to 1 Definition):**

```
public class MembershipMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Membership>
{
    public MembershipMap()
    {
        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        //**Relationship Mappings
        this.HasRequired(m => m.Profile)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Membership);

        //Properties & Column mapping
        this.Property(m => m.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PKID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(m => m.UserName)
            .HasColumnName("Username")
            .HasMaxLength(255);

        this.Property(m => m.Approved)
            .HasColumnName("IsApproved");

        this.Property(m => m.Locked)
            .HasColumnName("IsLocked");

        this.Property(m => m.CreatedOn)
            .HasColumnName("CreationDate");

        this.ToTable("AppUser");
    }
}
```

**Profile Mapping:**

```
public class ProfileMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Profile>
{
    public ProfileMap()
    {
        //Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        //Properties & Column mapping
        this.Property(m => m.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PKID")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(m => m.FirstName)
            .HasColumnName("FirstName");

        this.Property(m => m.LastName)
            .HasColumnName("LastName");

        this.Property(m => m.Email)
            .HasColumnName("Email");

        this.Property(m => m.Telephone)
            .HasColumnName("Telephone");

        this.Property(m => m.Extension)
            .HasColumnName("Extension");

        this.ToTable("AppUser");
    }
}
```

**Database Table**
I know that not all fields are mapped, but i do not need them at this stage, surely that wouldn't be the issue would it?

[image: AppUser Database Table]

Comment: Just to clarify, have you already run Migrations on this model?

Comment: I am currently not using any migrations, the database is pre-existing and the model of the classes should match the model of the database.  I am going through the whole thing now to see if this is somewhere else.

Comment: Try running the `update-database -script` command, and see what Migrations generates as a change script.  That should give you a clue as to what it's missing.

Comment: Thanks for that, after some pokery i got the script....its massive but i think i may know what is going on.  When i started this i was working with an existing DB, but the model is changing slightly so i took the tables that are staying the same and augmented the new structure.  The key thing is i changed the database and simplified the naming conventions, for instance "Projects" became "Project" how can i reset the migrations so i am basically starting again????

Comment: Personally, I just delete the Migrations folder that's been added to the project.  Bit heavy handed though!

Comment: Hmmm, to be honest until you mentioned the above i didn't actually have migrations turned on for this project which makes this all the weirder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was not Code First Mappings but caused by me switching databases and some rouge migrations coming into play.

To reset migrations you can see the answer here from a follow up question:

[Resetting Context for Entity Framework 5 so it thinks its working with a initialised Database - Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107871/resetting-context-for-entity-framework-5-so-it-thinks-its-working-with-a-initial)

Kudos to EvilBHonda